# Is it wise to call array.splice() whenever a row is clicked in a grid

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to keep track of indexes/rows that are selected.  When a row is selected in a jqGrid, I have an event splice an array - add if selected, remove if deselected.

Is this wise?  I just have a "doesn't seem like a good idea" feeling, so I'm really just looking for some validation one way or another :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a problem with it.  A smart alternative might be to toggle a `.selected` class, then access the elements using `$('.selected')` when you need to.

Comment: Hmm, I like that idea.  I'd toggle a class, then when the dialog closes, get all the .selected rows.  I may look into that, thanks Andy!

Answer (score 2):

it depends of what you need to do with that information. If you want to change the layout/styles of the rows the solution that Andy presented fits perfectly well. However if you need that indexes for data management you better use your method.